# Ordering MySQL data with different numbers of digits

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble ordering using MySQL as when using the standard

```
ORDER BY c DESC
```

it is ordering in like this:

```
3
21
20
2
```

I want it to be order like this:

```
21
20
3
2
```

Is there any way I can do this without adding 0 before the single digit numbers?

Comment: what is the data type of the column? I think it is a varchar, you need to convert it to number to have right ordering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your column from a string (VARCHAR, TEXT, etc.) to a numeric one (DOUBLE, INT, etc.). A string will be sorted alphabetically, and 3 comes after 2.

Or, you can cast it, but this adds processing to the query:

```
ORDER BY CAST(c AS INTEGER) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your field is a varchar. Change the type or cast it.

```
ORDER BY cast(c as unsigned) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a [converted to numeric representation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) of that column.